# Do an action when an error occurs RxJava

Tags: error-handling, rx-java, rx-android

I need to create a folder when it doesn't exist. In my case, the only way to do so is to capture the error and handle it to create the folder wanted.
But all i can find is

```
public static Observable<Boolean> folderExists(final Context context, final String targetPath, final String currentpath) {
    Application application = Application.get(context);
//i browse the folder to get all the items
        return browseFolderObservable(context,currentpath)
                .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
                .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        BsSdkLog.d("Error no file found");
                    }
            })

            .map(new Func1<ArrayList<Item>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(ArrayList<Item> items) {

                    if(items.isEmpty()) {

                        BsSdkLog.d(" No items");
                        return false;
                    }else  {
                        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
                        {
                            Item item=items.get(i);
                            BsSdkLog.d(item.toString());
                        }
                        BsSdkLog.d("Right-here");
                        return true;

                    }
                }
            });


}
```

I want to call the method that i have that creates the folder when the error occurs but i don't know how to do that. 
I'm new to this so i'd really appreciate the help 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to write to external or internal storage on the android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic principe looks like this. I used the Java NIO library for testing.

The method *'createFolder'* just wraps creating a folder. The test *'name'* invokes the Single and checks for an Exception. If it is an IOException it will return a fallback value. You may do something different in there. You just provide a fallback single. If it is an error different from IOException, it will return the error.

```
@Test
void name() throws Exception {
    final String TO_CREATE = "/home/sergej/Downloads/Wurstbrot";
    this.createFolder(TO_CREATE)
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> { // handle Exception:
                // Validate Exception
                if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
                    // Return fallback
                    return Single.just(Paths.get("/home/sergej/Downloads/"));
                }

                return Single.error(throwable);

            })
            .test()
            .await()
            .assertValueCount(1)
            .assertValue(path -> path.endsWith(TO_CREATE))
            .assertNoErrors();

}

private Single<Path> createFolder(String p) {
    return Single.defer(() -> { // may throw some IOException

        Path path = Paths.get(p);

        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            Path createdDirectory = Files.createDirectory(path); // will throw if already exists

            return Single.just(createdDirectory);
        }

        // Or just return Path, because it already exists???
        return Single.error(new IOException("Already exists"));
    });
}
```